# Do you actually say "I find this ..."?

Tags: phrase-meaning

For me it sounds weird, but I was wondering if and how often native English speakers use the phrase: "I find this ..." to express their opinion, like: "I find this interesting" or "I find this is a stupid idea".

Comment: Yes, I find that to be a natural phrasing, given the right context. :)

Comment: Yes, it's common, but I feel like [we usually say "I find it *noun-phrase*" rather than "I find it **is** **noun-phrase**"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+find+it+a%2CI+find+it+is+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20find%20it%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20find%20it%20is%20a%3B%2Cc0).  For example, "I find it a stupid idea" rather than "I find it is a stupid idea."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"I find this"** and **"I find that"** are both equally possible collocations in English.

However, here's the Ngram chart:

[image: Ngram Chart]

As you can see **"[I find it](http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/i-find-it-adjective-to-do-something--2)"** is most common because it's a **set phrase**, which *is used to describe opinions or feelings that you have. It's a slightly educated and formal-sounding phrase that you use to emphasize that what you're describing is your personal experience, not a suggestion that you are making to the listener.* *The word **"hard"** is especially common with **"I find it"**.*