# Is the phrase (I find it + verb) correct?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I was reading a comment and there's a part of his comment that makes me think, here is the screenshot:

[image]

Is the sentence **I find it works** even correct? Because, as far as I know, the phrase "I find it" is only followed by an adjective, isn't it?

From this [discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122148/do-you-actually-say-i-find-this), I conclude that I'm wrong and the phrase could be followed by a noun phrase and the verb "to be" (someone said in the comment it's uncommon, which means even a little, it's correct right?). I hope you would explain the detail and perhaps some examples would help me a lot to understand.

Comment: Imagine it with "that" added: "I find [that] it works both ways"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct colloquial English. I find it surprising you've not encountered that construction.

"It works both ways," is a complete clause, subordinate as used in your example, but it could be independent.

Think: "I find {something}."

```
I find it runs better on a smooth road.

She found it leaked from the bottom.
```

Comment: If I may ask again one more time please, the "it" part in the phrase "I find *it*", is it being an introductory word?

Comment: No, "it" is part of the clause.